# How can I execute this regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm used to using `Regex` in `PHP` but haven't really used it much in `Javascript`; I looked around but couldn't really find an answer other than just a bunch of tutorials on the regex syntax which I don't need.

For example I want to do the below, but with Regex:

```
if (location != '/group_breaks.php' && location != '/group_breaks' && location != '/group_breaks/') {

}
```

My regex would be: `/^\/group_breaks(\.php|\/)?$/`

So I could do this in `PHP` I could do:

```
if (!preg_match('/^\/group_breaks(\.php|\/)?$/', $location)) {

}
```

What is the alternative in Javascript?

Comment: Your regexp doesn't match `/group_breaks`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `?`. Edited.

Comment: No idea why the downvotes, cause I don't know how to implement regex in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript you can use:

```
if ( /^\/group_breaks(\.php|\/)?$/.test(location)) {
}
```

Remember to make `(\.php|\/)?` part optional so that it matches `/group_breaks` OR `/group_breaks/` OR `/group_breaks.php`

Comment: Yep...... accidentally missed the `?` haha, thanks! What about if I wanted to make sure it *doesn't* match!? Can I put a `!` at the start?

Comment: Yes sure you can do `if ( !/^\/group_breaks(\.php|\/)?$/.test(location) ) {...}` as well. Since `regex.test` method returns `boolean`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `RegExp.test` which returns a boolean which tells if the string matches or not.

```
var yourStringHere = "This is a string";
if(/^\/group_breaks(\.php|\/)$/.test(yourStringHere)){
   // valid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your regex inside a negative lookahead.

```
/^(?!\/group_breaks(\.php|\/)?$)/gm
```

EXample:

```
> /^(?!\/group_breaks(\.php|\/)?$)/.test("/group_breaks.php")
false
> /^(?!\/group_breaks(\.php|\/)?$)/.test("/group_breaks/")
false
> /^(?!\/group_breaks(\.php|\/)?$)/.test("/group_breaks")
false
> /^(?!\/group_breaks(\.php|\/)?$)/.test("/group")
true
```